# Yii2 Basic Background change

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, yii2

I`m using bootstrap and I`m trying to set a background image for the login screen.I try with div with id  that catch all the things and set the background but didnt work .

Here my Login.php

```
<div id="bimg">
<div  class="site-login">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>Please fill out the following fields to login:</p>



    <?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'id' => 'login-form',
                'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
                'fieldConfig' => [
                    'template' => "{label}\n <div class=\"center\"><div class=\"col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div></div>",
                    'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label'],
                ],
    ]);
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['autofocus' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Write your email address']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['placeholder' => 'Write your password']) ?>

    <?=
    $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox([
        'template' => "<div class=\"col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3\">{input} {label}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
    ])
    ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
            <div>
                <?= Html::a(Yii::t("app", "Forgotten  password") . "?", ["/site/forgot"]) ?>
                <br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

and the class with path in bootstrap.css

```
#bimg{
width:100%;
background-image: url(../web/assets/css/images/5.jpg) !important;
```

}

Comment: @scits the added auto to the yii2 bootstrap in "web" 
but the css file is the "web-assets-css" that css is the bootstrap.css file
and the problem is that I set the path to the image , but dont get it , but if I use background-color : red ;  it goes red as background

Comment: now it goes cut http://prnt.sc/ciagzh dont go on all of the background ....

Comment: @RosS ,set height and width for div

Comment: I set width: 100%;
     height: 100%; for that div with the class , but if i set div { width: 100%;
     height: 100%; background: url("images/3.jpg"); } it start to get messy

Comment: You should provide how it looks like. I can't tell what's wrong right now.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas http://prntscr.com/cjp8zz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layouts-main.php
controller->action->id == 'login') ? 'background-wrapper' : NULL ?>">
Check on which page u are , and if u are the page u want set the "class" u want